# Is there a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

It seems that such a metric doesn't exist,but how to prove?

Comment: There is a bijection $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Q$. Then use the pullback metric.

Comment: Of course it's not a metric giving the usual topology, because "dense" is a topological property.

Comment: @John Ah,bingo!